# Selenium chromeDriver crash “UnreachableBrowserException/

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Hi I apologise for a repost but I am new to selenium and tried to launch this simple command to open youtube in a google. However, it keeps crashing and showing this error. Directly below is the code I am running.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
     "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver"));
      WebDriver driver3 = new ChromeDriver();
      driver3.get("https://www.youtube.com/");
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong. Thank you

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Exception in thread "main"        
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start  
a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server 
or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'nuigit450', ip: '192.168.16.22', os.name: 'Windows  
7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_111'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at              org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:622)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:174)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:163)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
at TestWeb.main(TestWeb.java:22)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The process has not exited yet therefore no result is available ...
at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecuteResultHandler.getException(DefaultExecuteResultHandler.java:76)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess.checkForError(UnixProcess.java:173)
at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.checkForError(CommandLine.java:185)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:177)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:78)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Which versions of chrome and chromedriver do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webdriver.chrome.driver point to Chrome browser but it should point to chromedriver. For reference: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started

You need to download chromedriver from here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads and set path to this file in webdriver.chrome.driver.

Comment: Thank you Mackowski, It was a beginners mistake to make I replace   "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"); with  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe"); and it worked.